# How to push several images to Docker hub from one Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

In my project I have 3 Dockerfiles, one for the main project, one for my database and one for an nginx server. They are all in different folders in my project structure.

I am trying to get my Azure pipeline to build each of the corresponding images separately and push 3 separate images to Docker hub, one for each Dockerfile. However, my artifact from the build pipeline contains only 1 Dockerfile as you can see in the image below. From the logs it seems that this is the Dockerfile from my database folder, which is also the first folder in my project structure. Is there a way to get the pipeline to build and push 3 images, one for each Dockerfile?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your build definition, where you're probably not copying all the necessary files to folder from where you're publishing your build artifact.

So if your aim is to first create a build artifact with three separate docker files, you'll need to copy necessary files to artifact staging directory, and then publish it. For example:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: 'SomeContainer\'
    contents: '**'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\SomeContainer' 

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: MyContainersBuildArtifact
```

Add copy steps as necessary and create a folder structure you need under ArtifactStagingDirectory.

The copy files-task also has some examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#usage

You can also build and push the images as part of the build, or make the artifact in release definition to point straight to the source control repository.